# Ruby geocoder: Geocoding a second set of coordinates on the same model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, geocoding

We want to let our website's members list a second home, for those who spend the winter in one place and the summer in another. [geocoder's documentation](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#advanced-database-queries) explains how to perform a query on a second set of coordinates, but it doesn't say how to set the second pair of coordinates in the database so we can search on them.

If we do this, for example:

```
geocoded_by :location, latitude: :latitude, longitude: :longitude
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj) { obj.location.present? && obj.location_changed? }
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude, :longitude, location: :location do |obj, results|
  if (geo = results.first)
    obj.city         = geo.city
    obj.state        = geo.state
    obj.country      = geo.country
    obj.state_code   = geo.state_code
    obj.country_code = geo.country_code
  end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode, if: ->(obj) { obj.location.present? && obj.location_changed? }

geocoded_by :location2, latitude: :latitude2, longitude2: :longitude2
after_validation :geocode, if: ->(obj) { obj.location2.present? && obj.location2_changed? }
reverse_geocoded_by :latitude2, :longitude2, location: :location2 do |obj, results|
  if (geo = results.first)
    obj.city2         = geo.city
    obj.state2        = geo.state
    obj.country2      = geo.country
    obj.state_code2   = geo.state_code
    obj.country_code2 = geo.country_code
  end
end
after_validation :reverse_geocode, if: ->(obj) { obj.location2.present? && obj.location2_changed? }
```

It seems like the second `geocoded_by` overwrites the first instead of adding a second action. Can anyone suggest a way to do this?

Thanks very much!

Comment: a better architecture would be to say `user has_many :locations` (or limit it to two) and then geocode the location in itself. alternatively you can just have locations as a model (geocoded) and the user `has_one :primary_location, class_name: "Location"` and a `secondar_location` where you have a `primary_location_id`

Comment: Thanks for the ideas, @TimKretschmer! But once I've moved the geocoded data into a separate model, how do I do the equivalent of `User.near('Omaha, NE, US')` (incorporating both the primary and secondary locations)? I see how I would query locations, but how would I query users near those locations?

Comment: That's very easy and possible with a join or 2 seperated querys. 

Basically you want `Location.near("Omaga, NE, US")` and then `pluck(:user_id)`. Then `User.where(id: near_ids)`. 
Or you can figure it out in one go with a join. But this is the way to go.

Comment: Thanks, @TimKretschmer! I haven’t forgotten you. I started to use your ideas, then realized we could do the same for other parts of our site with addresses (places, groups, events, etc.), so I expanded the plan to incorporate polymorphic associations and am knee-deep in resulting difficulties.  I will report back when I have it working.

Comment: that sounds about correct. basically a model for all locations, which becomes geocoded and all other models can reference to one of those locations. easy as that.

Answer (score 0):

Thank again for your help, @TimKretschmer; it's worked well for us. A couple of caveats for anyone following this path:

First, if you create a polymorphic association, Locations will be tied both to the models that use them and the specific instances of those models. This means that, at best, you can create (and index on) a single Location for each User + user_id, each Event + event_id, etc., etc. This is a little disappointing — I would have preferred a single Location for "Paris" that *everything* used. I doesn't even look like I can have a single Location for all Users; there's going to be a "Paris" location for User 3 and another "Paris" for user 437.

Still, it's working. I cleaned it up a bit by running the users' input through Geocoder and saving the results if we get a hit:

```
def create
    location = Geocoder.address(params[:user][:location])
    params[:user][:location] = location unless location.nil?
    location2 = Geocoder.address(params[:user][:location2])
    params[:user][:location2] = location2 unless location2.nil?
    @user = User.new(user_params)

   [etc.]

 end
```

Most importantly, anyone doing this needs to be aware that [the way Geocoder uses ActiveRecord](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder#activerecord) means you can't use `pluck` with `near`. I ended up using `map` instead:

```
User.where(id: [Location
        .where(locatable_type: 'User')
        .near(@search_place, @search_distance)
        .map(&:locatable_id)])
```

Best wishes,
Jeff